# Imap could not open stream on live server

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap, gmail-pop

I am using imap_open to get email from gmail so its work on local server but when itry on live server it shows error.

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com}INBOX

```
$server = "{imap.gmail.com/imap/ssl}";
$username = "mymail@gmail.com";
$password = "mypass";

$conn = imap_open ( $server , $username , $password );
$mailboxes = imap_list( $conn, $server, "*" );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($mailboxes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for $server

```
   '{imap.gmail.com:995/imap/ssl}INBOX'
```

Comment: i already use this and also try some other 
these are work on local server perfactly but when i try my script on  live server its give me error.
is there any other solution

Comment: basically i want to count read unred emails of gmail.
before this i use curl to get result but same error.

Comment: may be your port not supporting ,please use 995 port

Comment: "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX" also try this too

Answer (score 1):

```
$server = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX";
$user   = "yourusername"; //do not include  @gmail.com nor googlemail.com
$passwd = "yourpassword";
$mbox = imap_open($server,$user,$passwd) or die("Could not open Mailbox - try again later!");
```